# DividerItemDecoration setDrawable getting multiple shapes dividers - not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am modifying the persistence sample and adding some divider lines to the RecyclerView instead of using CardView. If I don't customize the DividerItemDecoration, it works, and I get the divider lines. However if I customize it by using setDrawable I get something that looks like the image below. What am I doing wrong?

WordListFragment.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.words_list);
        DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.custom_divider));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);


        final WordListViewModel viewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordListViewModel.class);

        subscribeUi(viewModel);
   }
```

custom_divider.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
<size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

After commenting out setDrawable:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Height in your drawable. Try adding width too.

```
  <size
     android:width="1dp"
     android:height="1dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason after I did a Build, Make Project it seemed to start working. Not a good answer, but if I find out more I will update.

Update: this problem happened again after I did a database version change, but then again... I did a Build / Make Project and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a drawable layout, you can set both the **size** and **color** of the dividers using a GradientDrawable:

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{0xfff7f7f7, 0xfff7f7f7});
drawable.setSize(1,1);
itemDecoration.setDrawable(drawable);

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```